# I beginning and I would like know this simple code don't working (more précissely the method attack player)?

Tags: python, object, methods

```py
class Character:
    def __init__(self, name, strong, health, speed, dodge, intelligence):

        self.name = name
        self.strong = strong
        self.health = health
        self.speed = speed
        self.dodge = dodge
        self.intelligence = intelligence

    def damage(self):
        self.health -= self.strong + self.intelligence * 0.5 * (self.speed / 100 + 1)

    def attack_player(self, target_player):
        target_player.damage

    def get_health(self):
        return self.health

Bob = Character("Bob", 2, 25, 3, 8, 9 )
print("The first character is", Bob.name, "strong:", Bob.strong, "health:", Bob.health, "speed:", Bob.speed, "dodge:", Bob.dodge, "intelligence:", Bob.intelligence)

Tom =  Character("Tom", 5, 23, 6, 2, 1 )
print("The second character is", Tom.name, "strong:", Tom.strong, "health:", Tom.health, "speed:", Tom.speed, "dodge:", Tom.dodge, "intelligence:", Tom.intelligence)

Tom.attack_player(Bob)
print("It left ", Bob.health, "point of life at Tom")
```

Comment: Your `attack_player()` method does nothing. Did you mean it to do: `target_player.damage()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write `target_player.damage` you are just returning a reference to the function `damage` instead of actually executing the function. As one of the comments said you have to write the `attack_player` function as:

```
 def attack_player(self, target_player):
        target_player.damage()
```

Edit: This is not exactly what you asked but one comment mentioned that when a player takes damage it looks only at it's own stats to take that amount of damage. You probably want the damage function to have a parameter with the stats you want from the player that calls the `attack_player` function.

Comment: thanks, otherwise how can I do for the function to take the parameter of attacking character  ?

Comment: Assuming you want the attacked character to receive the damage using the same function you used but with the attacker's stats you should define the damage function as something like:
`
def damage(self, attackerStrong, attackerIntelligence, attackerSpeed):
    self.health -= attackerStrong + attackerIntelligence * 0.5 * (attackerSpeed / 100 + 1)

`

and call it in the attack function like:
`
def attack_player(self, target_player):
        target_player.damage(self.strong, self.intelligence, self.speed)

`